# Javascript POST behaving differently with Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a web server running from an embedded system, and the user has the option to upload files to the unit using POST, which works great until I use Safari, then it jumps straight to 100%.

Here is the (updated) code I'm using, called after the user selects a file to upload from a form, with some of the comments below added in:

```js
    // Create the form object
    uploadFormData = new FormData(uploadForm);
    // Initiate the AJAX request
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Ensure the request method is POST
    request.open('POST', uploadForm.action);
    // Attach the progress event handler to the AJAX request
    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', event => {
        // Add the current progress to the button
        var progressPc = Math.round((event.loaded/event.total)*100);
        console.log(`event loaded ${event.loaded} of total ${event.total}`);
        uploadForm.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = `<div>Uploading... (${progressPc}%)</div>`;
        // Update the progress bar
        uploadForm.querySelector('.progress').style.display = "block";
        uploadForm.querySelector('.progress').style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #25b3FF, #870404 ${progressPc}%, #e6e8ec ${progressPc}%)`;

    });
```

On Chrome this all works perfectly. On Safari, it shows as 100% complete immediately.

Any Safari-gurus out there who can see a problem with the above code? Any thoughts gratefully received.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the result of `Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100) + '%)'`.  It looks like you meant to concatenate that to `progressBar.innerHTML`, but there's a missing `+`.

Comment: Did you "redact" the `+`?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Hehe yep, when trying to fit the lines into the box I lost a + (in the original code progressBar.innerHTML and .style.background are on one line and work fine.

Comment: General programming advice: Assign `Math.round(event.loaded / event.total) * 100)` to a variable so you don't have to write it over and over.

Comment: And use template literals instead of concatenation.

Comment: On the console there are no errors, but on the embedded system, I receive a file of length 0 bytes (should be around 64kB). Chrome is sending the file and I receive all 65024 bytes at the other end

Comment: When you view the post in the Network tab of the web inspector, do you see the file being uploaded.

Comment: Thanks for your general advice, Barmar. I've assigned the output of the round function to a variable: progressPercent, then used that as ${progressPercent} rather than concatenation, so things are looking cleaner, but it's somewhat of an aside to the main problem I'm having of Safari not sending the file.

Comment: I know. My comment about checking the Network tab is directed at the main problem. You have debugging tools, use them.

Comment: On the Network tab, loadWaveMap.cgi gets sent immediately, whereas on Chrome it shows as Pending then sent after 1.5 sec or so. In each case only the header size of 143 bytes is shown

Comment: For whatever reason, Safari seems to think the file you've selected is empty. Are you sure the code is running after you select something?

Comment: Look in the Payload to see what it's actually sending.

Comment: Add `console.log(filesIn.files[0].name)` to see what file it thinks it's uploading.

Comment: There seems to be the full payload there (about 64kB), but it appears to be smashing it out without waiting for the embedded system's flow control, which takes a while as it needs to write the file to Flash memory. It seems the issue is more on the TCP/IP handshaking end and not with the javascript.

Comment: Update: I've not gotten Safari to send the file correctly, so TCP/IP layer is sorted out, but it still shows as 100% complete as soon as the you start, so the Event Listener for progress is getting event.loaded equal to event.total right off the bat

Comment: Maybe use a packet capture tool like `tcpdump` or Wireshark to see what the browser is actually sending on the wire.